# Can not upgrade Kali,not enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives

Tags: filesystems, kali-linux, disk-usage

I installed Kali Linux on VM VirtualBox(my host is Ubuntu 18.04). I am newbee to Kali,but the two linked questions are not related to my problem.
When I try to upgrade Kali

```
apt upgrade

926 upgraded, 81 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,503 MB of archives.
After this operation, 622 MB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
root@kali:~# df -H
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                       4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      837M  9.8M  827M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/kali--vg-root   12G   11G  250M  98% /
tmpfs                      4.2G   14M  4.2G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                      4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                  247M   63M  172M  27% /boot
tmpfs                      837M   17k  837M   1% /run/user/130
tmpfs                      837M   33k  837M   1% /run/user/0
```

How should I change my filesystem configuration?
udev is not used at all,why?

Output with nodes
df --o

```
Filesystem                Type      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% 1K-blocks     Used   Avail Use% File Mounted on
udev                      devtmpfs 1015859    390 1015469    1%   4063436        0 4063436   0% -    /dev
tmpfs                     tmpfs    1021292    744 1020548    1%    817036    10016  807020   2% -    /run
/dev/mapper/kali--vg-root ext4      701760 395200  306560   57%  10985352 10165868  241744  98% -    /
tmpfs                     tmpfs    1021292     45 1021247    1%   4085168     5340 4079828   1% -    /dev/shm
tmpfs                     tmpfs    1021292      3 1021289    1%      5120        0    5120   0% -    /run/lock
tmpfs                     tmpfs    1021292     17 1021275    1%   4085168        0 4085168   0% -    /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                 ext2       62248    339   61909    1%    240972    60868  167663  27% -    /boot
tmpfs                     tmpfs    1021292     24 1021268    1%    817032       16  817016   1% -    /run/user/130
tmpfs                     tmpfs    1021292     32 1021260    1%    817032       32  817000   1% -    /run/user/0
```

pvscan

```
root@kali:~# pvscan
PV /dev/sda5 VG kali-vg lvm2 [12.40 GiB / 20.00 MiB free]
Total: 1 [12.40 GiB] / in use: 1 [12.40 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0 ]
root@kali:~# pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sda5
VG Name kali-vg
PV Size 12.40 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
Allocatable yes 
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 3175
Free PE 5
Allocated PE 3170
PV UUID R2DnVQ-PUE9-OHbq-2jkh-J5U6-UBik-yJdQGg
```

And it warns about disk usage
[image]

Comment: You're running LVM for your root filesystem so you may be able to extend it. Have you checked if there's any space in your PV? (`pvs` and then maybe `lvextend`).

Comment: Since it's Kali and you won't be using it as a primary OS you may be able to delete whatever has filled up your root partition. That would get you back several GB.

Comment: @roaima How to delete tmpfs?

Comment: This is, IMHO, not a duplicate of the "Why is Kali so hard" question.  It's a fairly obvious case of not having allocated enough space for a disk in VirtualBox.

Comment: There's no point deleting a `tmpfs` as it's memory-based. You need either to review the stuff you've created but not deleted or to increase the sieve available in Vbox for your root PV, and thence your root LV. It really would be worth drilling down into `/usr` to see what's eating all the disk space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you surmised, the issue is simply that you don't have enough space in your VirtualBox instance.

This line says it all:

```
/dev/mapper/kali--vg-root   12G   11G  250M  98% /
```

So you only have 250 MB of vacant space. And as `apt` is helpfully telling you:

> After this operation, 622 MB of additional disk space will be used.

The solution is simple. Just extend the Logical Volume (LV) that your Virtualbox instance is living on. `lvextend` should do it. `man lvextend` should give you sufficient information. Ask on the site or in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you need more help.

Comment: `pvs` shows there is nothing free and available to extend within the existing space

Comment: @roaima Yes, we covered that in chat. He's not allocated space to the VB instance properly. He has plenty of space available in the host, though  he isn't using LVM there.

Answer (score 4):

Backup the virual machine ( clone it) then resize the virtual hard drive:

To incrase the kali.vdi from ~10 G to ~20 G use the following command (from Ubuntu):

```
VBoxManage modifyhd /Path/to/kali.vdi --resize 20000
```

Then download [Gparted](https://gparted.org/download.php) or use a linux live USB.

From Virtualbox, navigate to *Setting > Storage > Controller IDE* , then attach the gparted.iso

Configure the Virtual-Machine to boot from the optical drive (under *Settings > System > Motherboard*)

The virtual machine will boot into Gparted, you will be able to resize the virtual hard drive (10 ~> 20 G), apply changes , exit (shutdown)

Remove the attached gpartd.iso from the Controller IDE, then boot your virtual machine.

Comment: Why do you suggest all the juggling with a live iso? IMHO all that's needed is to run `fdisk /dev/sda` (or any other partitioning tool) from Kali, enlarge sda5 (delete & recreate with the same start sector), reboot and `pvextend`. Or if OP is not brave enough to play with sda5, create a new partition, `pvcreate` and `vgextend`.

Comment: It's a virtual machine with root on an LV. Extend the allocated disk. Extend the PV. Extend the LV. At most only the first operation requires the VM to be shut down, and possibly not even that.